# Why I can't get results with different rows in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

When I make a query in MySQL on my website it shows entries only if in the table there are multiple identical rows

table

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+  
| pid | uid | lpa | lar |  
+-----+-----+-----+-----+    
|  1  |  1  | AA  | BB  |  
|  2  |  1  | CC  | CC  |  
|  3  |  1  | AA  | AA  |  
|  4  |  1  | AA  | AA  |  
|  5  |  1  | DD  | EE  |
|  6  |  1  | CC  | CC  |
|  7  |  1  | AA  | CC  |
|  8  |  1  | FF  | FF  |
|  9  |  1  | AA  | BB  |  
+-----+-----+-----+-----+  



$query0 = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT pid, uid, lpa, lar
FROM table
WHERE lpa = 'AA' AND lar = 'BB'"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query0); 
mysqli_close($con);  
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query0)) { 
echo "
<tr>
<td>" . $row['pid'] . "<br></td>
<td>" . $row['uid'] . "<br></td>
<td>" . $row['lpa'] . "<br></td>
<td>" . $row['lar'] . "<br></td>
</tr>
"; 
}
```

in the WHERE clause if there are two identical rows in the table I can get results, else the results table is empty!

EDIT: Sorry, I already use the apex, I just forgot to write it here.

Comment: Literal strings (such as 'AA' and 'BB') should be quoted in your SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think marked **Here** `mysqli_fetch_array()` in below code should is deleted.

```
$query0 = mysqli_query($con, " SELECT pid, uid, lpa, lar FROM table WHERE lpa = 'AA' AND lar = 'BB'"); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query0); 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <= "Here"

mysqli_close($con);  

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query0)) 
{ 
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td>" . $row['pid'] . "<br></td>
    <td>" . $row['uid'] . "<br></td>
    <td>" . $row['lpa'] . "<br></td>
    <td>" . $row['lar'] . "<br></td>
    </tr>
    "; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally the solution! :D

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
SELECT pid, uid, lpa, lar
FROM table
WHERE lpa = 'AA' AND lar = 'BB'"
```

You should quote the strings..if its integer or float..its ok

Comment: Sorry, I already use the apex, I just forgot to write it here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query0 = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT pid, uid, lpa, lar
FROM table
WHERE lpa = 'AA' AND lar ='BB'");
```

Comment: Sorry, I already use the apex, I just forgot to write it here.